# Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.infinispan.commons.CacheException

Tags: caching, wildfly, infinispan

i am trying to upgrade jboss 4 to jboss 7 and using wildfly 10 for research purpose.

now i got error saying

> Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   org.infinispan.commons.CacheException from [Module
>   "deployment.mes-webservices.ear:main" from Service Module Loader]
>
> at
>   org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:198)
>
> at
>   org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:363)
>
> at
>   org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:351)
>
> at
>   org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:93)
>
> ... 299 more

when i debug i see that error initiated here.

```
cachedBom = (BillOfMaterials) **CacheManager**.fetchObjectFromCache(bomFqn, bomKey);
```

where cacheManager refers here.

```
private static final String CACHENAME = "ClusteredTreeCache";

protected static final Log log = LogFactory.getLog(CacheManager.class);

private static  EmbeddedCacheManager   myCacheManager;

private  static Cache cache = myCacheManager.getCache();

private static  TreeCache  mCache;



private static void findCache() throws MalformedObjectNameException

{





    // Find the shared cache service in JMX and create a proxy to it

ObjectName cacheServiceName_ = new ObjectName("java:jboss/infinispan/replicated_cache/customer");

// Create Proxy-Object for this service

myCacheManager = new DefaultCacheManager();



mCache = new TreeCacheFactory().createTreeCache(cache);



// Log that medtronicCache Proxy saved

log.info("mCache Proxy Object has been set.   Should only happen once.");

}

Standalone :
 <cache-container name="replicated_cache" default-cache="default" module="org.wildfly.clustering.server" jndi-name="infinispan/replicated_cache">
                <transport lock-timeout="60000"/>
                <replicated-cache name="customer" jndi-name="infinispan/replicated_cache/customer" mode="SYNC">
                    <transaction locking="OPTIMISTIC" mode="NON_XA"/>
                    <eviction strategy="NONE"/>
                </replicated-cache>
            </cache-container>
```

Comment: Added quote and code block

Answer (score 2):

The problem seems to be that org.infinispan.commons.CacheException is not in your runtime classpath. Please check that:

- infinispan-commons.jar is part of your deployment
- or that you have jboss-deployment-structure.xml which declares a dependency to the org.infinispan.commons module
- or that you have a manifest dependency to the org.infinispan.commons module

You could check my [demo project](https://github.com/stefangrossmann/infinispan-jcache-example/tree/master) at Github.